# Java process manager

Tags: java, process

I made an app that use 6 process. There is no option for me to reduce this number.

I used to start those processed from java with some module I build around:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
```

But it created a lot of troubles with errors handling. Terminating a process is not trivial.

So I moved to command line, and I wrote a batch script to start 6 command prompt(Windows consul window), now closing those also kill the process, so error handling become easier.

But it look very bad... Messy...

I guess this is not a common way to work, so my question is what is? How to manage multiple java processes with the next behaviors:

- Process can crash
- Optionally there is a dependency between processes, so if process A is terminated/crash, process B should be terminated as well, it's optional as it's easier for me to manage it this way, but I can code around it, so it's not mandatory.
- Process can be force stopped with some timeout if it fails to complete it's task.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. You say "Terminating a process is not trivial." Why not? What doesn't work with `Process.destroy()` ? What OS are you running this on?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You should google a little bit about Process.destroy(). It's not working well in java, regardless the OS. In my case I work with Windows, but I can move to different OS.

Comment: You're the one asking the question. If you can't use the most obvious thing you should show that research in your question to make it more useful.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In [those comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5776869/1129332) you can find some of the problems with Process.destroy. I think most people aware of that.

Comment: Are you serious? These comments are jokes about skynet. The answer that they comment on says you should use `Process.destroy()`. It's not relevant in any case, the relevance to your question is: what problems do **you** have with `Process.destroy()` if any. Show that in your question.